# How can I do same calculation in numpy array list at once?

Tags: python, numpy, std, mean

I want to normalize my list containing 2D NumPy arrays of different sizes with `axis=1`.
My NumPy array list is like below:

[image]

First, I tried to get mean and std using `numpy.hstack`.

An error occurred in the following operation that was successfully obtained:

```
mean,std = get_mean_std(uttrSpectro) # get_mean_std : my function which returns mean and std
uttrSpectro = (uttrSpectroList-mean)/std
```

```
Error Message : could not broadcast input array from shape (801,284) into shape (801)
```

How can I do this calculation without for-loop?

Comment: Use `keepdims=True` when computing `mean` values, if you are using `numpy.mean`.

Comment: Once you store Python lists in a DataFrame, if you wish to apply a function to all the lists, you are forced to use a Python-speed loop to iterate over the items and you are forced to apply a function to each list separately. There are no fast vectorized operations for Python lists.

Comment: To leverage NumPy/Pandas for speed, do not store lists in DataFrames. Store the variabled sized lists as one large NumPy array, using  NaNs for missing values. Then you could take advantage of `np.nanmean` and `np.nanstd` to compute all the means and std deviations for each row at once.

Comment: Thank you so much!!